# mouse click not registered in trailing whitespaces of a multi-line text when display:inline

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display an icon, a text, and another icon - as a continuous string of letters. The markup looks like:

```
<div class="scroll"...>
    <i class="icon ion-close" ng-click="removeItem(x)"></i>
    <div class="FOO" ng-click="clipboardItem(x)">
        A multi-line text message 
    <div>
    <i class="icon ion-clipboard" ng-if="..."></i>
</div>
```

When `FOO` is styled `display:block` (or `inline-block`) then clicking anywhere in the rectangular region of the multi-line text message is registered. But the two icons and text message come on separate line, not what I want.

When `FOO` is styled `display:inline` then visually it is a continuous string of icons and text, but a click in the whitespaces at end of a line break is not triggered. The user has to carefully position mouse on a letter and then click it. That's messy!

I would like to understand what's happening underneath and how to style it properly. What is so special about `inline` insofar as click area goes?

Using Chrome, Ionic, Angular, testing on Windows.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can we have a fiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pd8dLwv2/1/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pd8dLwv2/2/ is clearer to see

Answer (score 0):

I am having a hard time understanding what you want. 
Here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pd8dLwv2/6/

I wrapped your upper divs in an anchor and added a pointer so that the entire section is clickable.

```
    <a onclick="alert(99)" style="cursor:pointer">
    <div class="scroll" ...> <i class="icon ion-close" ng-click="removeItem(x)"></i>

        <div class="FOO">A multi-linetextmessage where mouse click region is not very intuitive unless it had a background A multi-linetextmessage where mouse click region is not very intuitive unless it had a background A multi-linetextmessage where mouse click region is not very intuitive unless it had a background A multi-linetextmessage where mouse click region is not very intuitive unless it had a background</div> 

        <div><i class="icon ion-clipboard" ng-if="..."></i>

    </div>
</div>

<hr/>
</a>
```

Comment: My question was why `inline` makes the browser not register clicks in the non-text areas (in my fiddle it is the pink-ish area in first div).